# How to prevent voltage variation in a fast-switching circuit with parallel connection?

Tags: circuit-design

I have designed a circuit in which 2 LEDs are connected in parallel and controlled by MOSFET gates (n channel). These MOSFET gates are driven by the output pins of an FGPA to switch them btw ON/OFF at high frequencies around 1KHz.

[image: circuit design]

As shown in the above figure, each LED is controlled by two MOSFET gates. I notice that when both MOSFET gates are switched at a close but different frequencies, say 1013 and 1023 Hz, the luminance of the LED slightly vary (Note that human eye can only perceive luminance change less than 60 Hz). However, if only one LED is connected, there is no human-observable luminance variation.

To find the problem, I connected an oscilloscope to the LED and notice there is a voltage variation btw the Drain and GND of the second MOSFET gate, the frequency of which is around 10Hz and is shown as follows:

[image: Voltage on the LED]

What is the reason for such variation? Is it connected to the voltage drop of breadboard? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The circuit is too vague. Where are the four (or three?) parallel LEDs? What do the blue circles represent?

Comment: Are you powering the 10W LEDs (3A each) via the breadboard?

Answer (score 3):

You have not given enough information in your question to provide a good answer.

The 10 Hz signal you are seeing is the "beat" or difference frequency between the two frequencies you are generating. This is a problem because your supply is not "stiff" enough. The voltage is drooping as current increases.

From Ohm's law we can work out that the resistance between the first and second LED is \$ R = \frac {V}{I} = \frac {0.2}{0.2} = 1 \; \Omega \$. This seems reasonable for a breadboard.

Try wiring the positive and negative of each of your circuits directly back to the power supply. (Don't use the common rail of your breadboard.) This "star" arrangement will avoid each circuit interfering with its neighbours.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIt3cJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1 R1 to 12 represent the wiring and contact resistance. (a) In this circuit the loads on the right will cause interference on the loads to the left. (b) In this circuit each load is powered directly from the power supply.*

In Figure 1b there will be no fluctuation in lamp voltage if the power supply is well regulated.